# How to ignore warning unrelated to package name in Proguard file?

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

I am working with Android Studio 3.0 and experience warnings after gradle build:

> AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"Transform
>   \u0027RealmTransformer\u0027 uses scope PROJECT_LOCAL_DEPS which is
>   deprecated and replaced with EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES","sources":[{},{}]}

I heard about the issue https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/4659 which explains the bug, but my question is unrelated. I am actually curious, if it's possible to ignore in build with Proguard shrinking warnings unrelated to any package name or class.

proguard-rules.pro with

```
-dontwarn **
-ignorewarnings
-dontwarn io.realm.**
```

simply doesn't work and I can't build the project with Proguard activated.

Comment: what version are you using?

Comment: The one integrated in gradle plugin `3.0.0-alpha1` which is
`net.sf.proguard:proguard-base:5.3.3`